# VBA copy cells value and format

Tags: excel, vba

How can I amend the following code in order to copy not only the value but also the fonts style, e.g. bold or not bold. Thanks

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Integer
Dim a As Integer
a = 15
For i = 11 To 32
  If Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 3) <> "" Then
    Worksheets(2).Cells(a, 15) = Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Value
    Worksheets(2).Cells(a, 17) = Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 5).Value
    Worksheets(2).Cells(a, 18) = Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 6).Value
    Worksheets(2).Cells(a, 19) = Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 7).Value
    Worksheets(2).Cells(a, 20) = Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 8).Value
    Worksheets(2).Cells(a, 21) = Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 9).Value
    a = a + 1
  End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 35):

Instead of setting the value directly you can try using copy/paste, so instead of:

```
Worksheets(2).Cells(a, 15) = Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Value
```

Try this:

```
Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Copy
Worksheets(2).Cells(a, 15).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Worksheets(2).Cells(a, 15).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

To just set the font to bold you can keep your existing assignment and add this:

```
If Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Font.Bold = True Then
  Worksheets(2).Cells(a, 15).Font.Bold = True
End If
```

Comment: Thank you this is very close to the result I want to have.However, instead of copying the entire format. Is there a way to furter narrow format copying. I just want to copy the font style. I have figures that bold, so i want them to be bold in the copied sheet as well.

Comment: +1 for this answser. Wondering if they are Boolean then maybe one line will work `Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Font.Bold = Worksheets(2).Cells(a, 15).Font.Bold`

Comment: @user3849959 Did my revised answer provide a solution for you? If it did you might consider marking it as accepted.

Comment: Not strictly relevant here, but in general, advisable to FIRST copy values (`Paste:=xlPasteValues`), and THEN copy format (`Paste:=xlPasteFormats`), to avoid issues with merged cells

Answer (score 5):

This page from Microsoft's Excel VBA documentation helped me: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpastetype

It gives a bunch of options to customize how you paste. For instance, you could **xlPasteAll** (probably what you're looking for), or **xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme**, or even **xlPasteAllExceptBorders**.

Answer (score 2):

Following on from jpw it might be good to encapsulate his solution in a small subroutine to save on having lots of lines of code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Integer
Dim a As Integer
a = 15
For i = 11 To 32
  If Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 3) <> "" Then
    call copValuesAndFormat(i,3,a,15)        
    call copValuesAndFormat(i,5,a,17) 
    call copValuesAndFormat(i,6,a,18) 
    call copValuesAndFormat(i,7,a,19) 
    call copValuesAndFormat(i,8,a,20) 
    call copValuesAndFormat(i,9,a,21) 
    a = a + 1
  End If
Next i
end sub

sub copValuesAndFormat(x1 as integer, y1 as integer, x2 as integer, y2 as integer)
  Worksheets(1).Cells(x1, y1).Copy
  Worksheets(2).Cells(x2, y2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
  Worksheets(2).Cells(x2, y2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
end sub
```

(I do not have Excel in current location so please excuse bugs as not tested)

Answer (score 2):

Found this on [OzGrid](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/32985-copying-cell-format-in-vba) courtesy of Mr. Aaron Blood - simple direct and works.

```
Code:
Cells(1, 3).Copy Cells(1, 1)
Cells(1, 1).Value = Cells(1, 3).Value
```

However, I kinda suspect you were just providing us with an oversimplified example to ask the question. If you just want to copy formats from one range to another it looks like this...

```
Code:
Cells(1, 3).Copy
    Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
```