# Copy Excel theme color in a new workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I want to make a macro that copies two sheets in a new workbook.
But the theme color in the new created workbook is different.

```
Sub Export_File()
Dim Wb3 As Workbook
Dim strSaveName As String

strSaveName = Worksheets("Communication").Range("a2").Value
Set Wb3 = ThisWorkbook
 
'copy sheets to new workbook
Sheets(Array("Auswertung", "Communication")).Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs strSaveName

Workbooks(Wb3).Colors = Workbooks(strSaveName).Colors

End Sub
```

This line does not work for me:

```
Workbooks(Wb4).Colors = Workbooks(strSaveName).Colors
```

I think it has something to do with Set *Wb4 = ThisWorkbook* Need help...

Greetings

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be working for me, to copy a workbook theme:

```
    '   copy the colors and themes
    '
    resultWorkbook.Colors = sourceWorkbook.Colors
    'Theme is not the same as colors
    Dim sourceTheme As Microsoft.Office.Core.ThemeColorScheme = sourceWorkbook.Theme.ThemeColorScheme 
    Dim resultTheme As Microsoft.Office.Core.ThemeColorScheme = resultWorkbook.Theme.ThemeColorScheme 

    For i = 1 To sourceTheme.Count  ' there are 12 theme colors: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa432704(v=office.12).aspx
        'Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("{0, -2} ~ {1}", i, sourceTheme.Colors(i).RGB))
        resultTheme.Colors(i).RGB = sourceTheme.Colors(i).RGB
    Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Worksheet.Copy` only takes the values, but if you set the script to copy the range of cells from one sheet to another, you can use `PasteSpecial` to copy both the values and the formats - example from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25461314/vba-copy-cells-value-and-format)

```
Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Copy
Worksheets(2).Cells(a, 15).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Worksheets(2).Cells(a, 15).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But this does not copy the color palette/theme color of the workbook. This code has the same effect as mine.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to transfer the theme would be to save the source theme as a temp xml and load that file into the destination theme.

```
DestWB.Colors = SourceWB.Colors
Dim TempThemeFile As String
Dim sourceTheme As Microsoft.Office.Core.ThemeColorScheme
set sourceTheme = sourceWorkbook.Theme.ThemeColorScheme 

'Late binding alternative:
'Dim sourceTheme As Object
'Set sourceTheme = SourceWB.Theme.ThemeColorScheme

TempThemeFile = Environ$("temp") & "\xltheme" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".xml"
sourceTheme.Save TempThemeFile
DestWB.Theme.ThemeColorScheme.Load TempThemeFile
Kill TempThemeFile
```