# Copy values and colors from one workbook to another without copying conditional formatting

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

I use this line of code to copy the contents of one workbook to another, but it only copies the values (and avoid getting `#VALUE` errors), but I am hoping to copy the color of the cell as well:

```
Workbooks("Payroll Data.xlsm").Worksheets("Pay-MR Compiled").Range("A" & Total_rows_PayMRCompiled + 1 & ":BD" & Total_rows_PayMRCompiled + Total_rows_PayMR - 1).Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pay-MR").Range("A2:BD" & Total_rows_PayMR).Value
```

My issue is that when I copy `Values & Source Formatting`, it also copies the conditional formatting rules and because my condition is using something like `NOT(ISFORMULA(A2))` function to check whether the cell is a formula or not, and the paste is only values, all will be colored.

For instance, only 1 cell is highlighted in the actual data as shown below:

[image: Before copy]

But what happens when pasting with `Values and Source Formatting` is:

[image: After copy]

Comment: Could you tell us what the actual conditional formatting going on here is please? It might help find the reason for this.

Comment: @Taazar Edited it the conditional will color up to yellow if the cells in the range is not a formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standing the conditional formatting formula you made clear, you could try this

```
Set sourceRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pay-MR").Range("A2:BD" & Total_rows_PayMR)        
With Workbooks("Payroll Data.xlsm").Worksheets("Pay-MR Compiled").Range(sourceRange.Address).Offset(Total_rows_PayMRCompiled - 1) ' reference "target" range
    .Value = sourceRange.Value ' paste "source" range values to referenced (i.e. "target") range
    .Interior.Color = sourceRange.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color ' color referenced (i.e. "target") range with conditional formatting color
    .Parent.Range(sourceRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Offset(Total_rows_PayMRCompiled - 1).Address).Interior.Pattern = xlNone 'clear the color of "target" sheet range corresponding to "source" range cells with formulas 
End With
```

If your "source" range conditional formatting has more than one formula, then just change the `1` in `FormatConditions(1).` to the proper format condition item number.

---

edited to add the `Total_rows_PayMRCompiled - 1` row offset in target range

Comment: I believe this code makes the `target` range to have all its cells the color yellow then it will make the `source` range lose it's color? My goal is actually to exactly copy the color scheme of the `source` range and pasting it in the `target` range as is. The only difference is that instead of formulas from the `source` range, it will only paste as values in the `target` range.

Comment: _"The conditional rule of interest is located at the 4th row of the Conditional Formatting Rules Manager"_ -> then use `Interior.Color = sourceRange.FormatConditions(4).Interior.Color`

Comment: Right sorry. I was looking at the wrong worksheet the color scheme is yellow as expected. Thank you `FormatConditions(4)` works, but moving to the 2nd issue, I only need the cell that is colored in the `source` to be colored in the `target`.

Comment: 1) _"I believe this code makes the target range to have all its cells the color yellow"_ -> yes.  2) _"then it will make the source range lose it's color?"_ -> no, it makes the target range cells whose address corresponds to the source range cells with formulas lose its color.  I edited the answer since I was missing the `Total_rows_PayMRCompiled - 1` row offset

Comment: I've tested the code, and I do get the isolated color, but the first few columns are all colored as shown: https://imgur.com/a/znpwqIK

Comment: then those first few columns do not contain formulas in "source" sheet

Comment: well... can't you simply un-check the wrong answer and check the right one?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no way to copy the formatting without the conditional formatting.
However, you could go the other way around: First copy values and formatting and remove the conditional formatting afterwards.

Your code could look like

```
Dim destRange as Range
Set destRange = Workbooks("Payroll Data.xlsm").Worksheets("Pay-MR Compiled").Range("A" & Total_rows_PayMRCompiled + 1 & ":BD" & Total_rows_PayMRCompiled + Total_rows_PayMR - 1)

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pay-MR").Range("A2:BD" & Total_rows_PayMR).Copy
destRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
destRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
destRange.FormatConditions.Delete
```

If the colors appears different on the destination, you might have different color schemes for the two workbooks. Have a look to https://stackoverflow.com/a/37423390/7599798 to how to copy the color settings.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I removed the equal sign at the end of this line `Set destRange = Workbooks("Payroll Data.xlsm").Worksheets("Pay-MR Compiled").Range("A" & Total_rows_PayMRCompiled + 1 & ":BD" & Total_rows_PayMRCompiled + Total_rows_PayMR - 1).Value =` but I get a subscript error on `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pay-MR").Range("A2:BD" & Total_rows_PayMR).Copy`

Comment: @DisplayName: Yes, but with own workbook/sheet names, made a C&P mistake when adapting the code to the one form OP - corrected it.

Comment: @Pherdiny: Please check my edit, sorry, made a mistake when adapting my test code to your workbook/sheet. If you get an *subscript error* at the `Copy`, it sounds as if there is a mistake in the sheetName  (`"Pay-MR"`)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `.DisplayFormat` method. check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841234.aspx)

Try like this

```
Set trgtCell = Workbooks("Payroll Data.xlsm").Worksheets("Pay-MR").Range("A2")
Set srcCell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pay-MR").Range("A2")

trgtCell.Value = srcCell.Value
trgtCell.Font.FontStyle = srcCell.DisplayFormat.Font.FontStyle
trgtCell.Interior.Color = srcCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
trgtCell.Font.Strikethrough = srcCell.DisplayFormat.Font.Strikethrough
trgtCell.Font.Color = srcCell.DisplayFormat.Font.Color
```

Comment: `trgtCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3` will give me a red fill on the range, but `trgtCell.Interior.Color = srcCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color` will give me a black fill on all the copied cells despite the source cell not being black.