# How to paste values and keep source formatting?

Tags: excel, vba, format

I am trying to copy some values from a column in one workbook to another:

Workbook 1

```
Column A
10/02/1990
41
11/01/2017
52
```

Workbook 2

```
Column I
10/02/1990
41
11/01/2017
52
```

If I simply copy my values from column 1 in workbook A and paste them to column I in workbook 2 I get results like so:

```
Column I
34331
41
121092
52
```

The formatting is lost/confused by Excel.

So I created a button where users can paste this data using VBA like so:

```
Sub Paste3()
Dim lastRow As Long
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ActiveSheet.Range("H10").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
MsgBox "Please Copy Values First."
End Sub
```

The values keep their formatting. However, the cell format also changes.

What I mean is, the cells on workbook 1 have a black border, and the font is also black and bold.

I want to preserve workbook 2's font and cell border. This is:

Grey border, RGB(191, 191, 191)
Grey Font (RGB 128, 128, 128)
Font Size: 11
Font: Calibri

Essentially it needs to look like the column to the right.

[image]

I tried this, but it adds borders to ranges in my spreadsheet it isn't supposed to.

```
Sub Paste3()
Dim lastRow As Long
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ActiveSheet.Range("H10").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("H10:H" & lastRow)
With rng.Borders
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Color = RGB(191, 191, 191)
    .Weight = xlThin
    .Font
End With
    
With rng.Font
    .TextColor = RGB(128, 128, 128)
    .Font.Name = "Calibri"
    .Size = 11
    .Bold = False
End With
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
MsgBox "Please Copy Values First."
End Sub
```

I would rather find an easier way of pasting these values and keeping their format without changing the cell format and font colour etc.

Comment: *Paste Values* pastes, well, *the values*. If you want to keep the *formatting* you need to paste more than just the *values*.

Comment: Try recording a macro while you manually perform the paste special operation, and see what parameters Excel is given for the `PasteSpecial` call.

Comment: Paste Values and Formats. Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25461314/vba-copy-cells-value-and-format

Answer (score 6):

There's a PasteSpecial option for this:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("H10").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, _
                 Operation:= xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of  just try< Paste:=xlPasteAll> once