# Copying data and conditional formatting from one workbook to another using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

I am trying to copy data and conditional formatting from one workbook to another. I can get the data to transfer over to my primary workbook, but the conditional formatting is being removed. How do I copy the data and conditional formatting from one workbook to another?

This is what I have so far:

```
Dim Master As Workbook 
Set Master = ActiveWorkbook 
Dim lastRow As Long 
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row 
Range("A2:AE2" & lastRow).Select Selection.Copy 
Master.Activate
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(lastRow, 1).Paste
```

I have tried Paste Special and it does not work either.

Comment: I think istead of `.Paste` you use `.PasteSpecial`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41725730/vba-paste-values-and-keep-source-formatting

Comment: I reviewed that same thread and thought that would work, but it did not. It pastes all the formatting, data, and cell borders but it does not copy over the conditional formatting. I have conditional formatting that highlights entire rows of the temporary spreadsheet based on an IFERROR statement in column A.

Comment: I created two excel workbooks, created a cell with conditional formatting in one and successfully copied it to another workbook with `Workbooks("book1").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a1").Copy Destination:=Workbooks("book2").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a1")`. The conditional formatting was copied over OK, so I would work from this and slowly change it to what you want and see when it stops working. Also what version of excel?

Comment: Also what is going on with the line `Range("A2:AE2" & lastRow).Select Selection.Copy`? I don't think that the select method has any parameters?

Comment: I am using Excel 2010. That did not work. PasteSpecial does not paste any information into my master workbook.

Comment: I didn't copy my entire VBA code over because the macro is huge. The `Range("A2:AE2" & lastRow).Select Selection.Copy` is copying range A2 to AE2 to the last row on my temporary workbook.

Comment: `Dim lastRow As Long lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row`

Answer (score 0):

Use `xlPasteFormats`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlpastetype.aspx

`ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(lastRow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats`

If that doesnt work, try pasting twice. First the values, then the formatting.

```
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(lastRow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(lastRow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
```

Comment: When I try this method, it does not paste anything from my temporary workbook. Any idea why that is?

Comment: Probably an issue with using ActiveSheet. Either be sure to select the appropriate sheet first `Sheets('mySheet').Select` -- or, better yet, just reference the sheet you want to copy from `ThisWorkbook.Sheets('mySheet').Cells`

Comment: So, when I copy the data from my temporary workbook, how should I write the code to switch back to my master spreadsheet and activate it? Right now I do that by:

`Master.Activate
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(lastRow, 1).PasteSpecial
Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, 
Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False`

Comment: Is the lastRow throwing it off? I don't believe it is, but I guess it could be possible.

Comment: As good practice, you shouldn't look to use ActiveSheet and instead, always use direct references to whatever sheet you intend to work with. You need not select a sheet prior to interacting with it so long as you reference it directly.

If you want to switch back to your master sheet, then the same applies, select and activate it. `Sheets('myMasterSheet').Select` then `Sheets('myMasterSheet').Activate` --- keeping in mind you dont need to actually select or activate a sheet if you reference it directly. `ThisWorkbook.Sheets('myMasterSheet').Cells`

Comment: Okay, I've made progress, but it's still not including the conditional formatting. This is what I have now:

` Master.Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lastRow, 1).PasteSpecial
Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone,
SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False`

Comment: Yes, lastRow could be throwing it off. I would replace all references to active sheet, with whatever sheet you intend to perform actions against. `lastRow = Sheets('mySheet').Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats is not the same as xlPasteFormats.

Comment: Running into the issue where it is no longer pasting any data now. xlPasteFormats pastes nothing and xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats pastes all data but no conditional formatting. This is extremely confusing.

Comment: My apologies for the confusion. `xlPasteFormats` pastes only the formatting, which includes any conditional formatting. If you use it by itself, nothing will happen as there are no values to format. Trying pasting twice, first the values, then the formats.

Comment: Pastes the data, but still not the conditional formatting.

Comment: Refer to this SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25768023/excel-copy-conditional-formatting-remove-rules-keep-format

Comment: I think that will work, thank you. I just need to figure out how to integrate it into my macro.