# Copying cells without the fomulas, but with format VBA

Tags: vba, excel

this macro copies the cells in another Workbook. How can I make it copy only the format and the values without the formulas.

```
    With Worksheets("Analysis")                             
            Range("A1:J35").copy                                        

            Windows("2016-Backtesting-Aggregation_EquityNEU.xlsx").Activate                                                             
            Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)                      
            Range("A1").PasteSpecial _                                  
            Operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd                       ´
 End With
```

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25461314/vba-copy-cells-value-and-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy the values and number formats (without formulas) use:

```
Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
```

To copy the values and entire format (cells formatting as well), use:

```
.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme '<-- cells background, etc.
```