# Maintain color and font when moving cells and skip blank cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below VBA script. It's simply moving information from one sheet to another. However, I want each cell moved to possess the same color and font in sheet2 as it had in sheet1. Cherry on top, when moving cells if I could get the script to skip over blank cells that would be amazing.

```
Sub Example()

lr = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Z65536").End(xlUp).Row
k = 0
For i = 5 To lr
k = k + 1

Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & k) = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Z" & i)
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & k) = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Z" & i)
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & k) = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Z" & i)
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & k) = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Z" & i)
k = k + 1
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & k) = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AA" & i)
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & k) = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AA" & i)
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & k) = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AA" & i)
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & k) = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AA" & i)

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25461314/vba-copy-cells-value-and-format  for format issue.  As far as the skipping blanks an IF that checks the values will do that.

Comment: Thank you! This helped a ton. I'll work on an IF statement for skipping blanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace lines like:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & k) = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Z" & i)
```

with:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Z" & i).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & k)
```

will maintain color and font.

Comment: Ah yeah, I don't know why I was complicating it. Thanks so much!