# How do i copy the formatting of a cell in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a **cell, with formatted (color, size, bold, ...) text** in it.
I want to edit the text with a user form (which works), but I **want, that the new text keeps the old texts formatting** (color, ...).

How do I do that? When I just copy the .Value in a Textbox, then change it in the textbox and paste the value into the cell, it loses its formatting.

Is there a way to get the value with its formatting? Like BBCodes ore Markdown formatting.

Thanks, Luca

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBA copy cells value and format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25461314/vba-copy-cells-value-and-format)

Comment: If you mean partial coloring of the text then the answer is no, there is no built in way to do that, you will have to re-color, re-fomat the whole text after re-writing the value to the cell.

Comment: Best to show the code you have, and describe exactly how the result you get differs from what you want

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because neither the question nor the answer seems to be helpful for future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by copying the cell with text formatting using the copy function and then editing the text and using Cells#Characters in a loop of the length of the text to change the font properties. Thanks for every answer!

Comment: ... and why didn't you use the "copy format"? Using this, you don't need to modify your text afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that you can record a macro and see what's inside?

I've just done a "copy/paste formatting", and the code looks as follows:

```
    Selection.Copy
    Range("C8").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

The most important part here is the `.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats`, which, as you can imagine, pastes the formatting but not the content.